# How to call NSPasteboard withUniqueName from Python using PyObjC

Tags: pyobjc

I am attempting to create a new pasteboard using the NSPasteboard class-level function withUniqueName from Python via PyObjC, however I get the error "AttributeError: No attribute withUniqueName".

This is my first use of PyObjC.  I did read the [PyObjC intro](https://pyobjc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core/intro.html) but I could very easily be calling it wrong.

This code yields the error:

```
from AppKit import *
pb = NSPasteboard.withUniqueName()
```

Based on the discussion of selectors in the intro, I also tried:

```
from AppKit import *
pb = NSPasteboard.withUniqueName_()
```

but that also gave an AttributeError.

This code (excerpted from http://www.macdrifter.com/2011/12/python-and-the-mac-clipboard.html works:

```
from AppKit import *
pb = NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
```

From the [NSPasteboard docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspasteboard#declarations) I see that withUniqueName is a class function whereas general is a class variable, so my attempt to invoke withUniqueName in the same way may be errant.

In attempting to determine whether I was just calling withUniqueName wrong or whether PyObjC didn't implement it, I did `dir(NSPasteboard)`.  withUniqueName was not in the list, but neither was "general" nor "generalPasteboard".  Even grepping through the installed modules, I could not find "general" nor "generalPasteboard", and I know the latter works, so that was frustrating my attempt at discovery.  Also I don't understand why the Python code needs to call the variable as generalPasteboard when the name in the Apple docs is just general.

I'm using PyObjC 5.2 installed from PyPI with Python 3.7.0 on Sierra 10.12.6.

Does PyObjC 5.2 support NSPasteboard withUniqueName?  If so, what is the correct way to call it?  If not, how would I inspect the module/class to know that?

Answer (score 0):

The name withUniqueName is the Swift name of this method, the Objective-C selector is `+[NSPasteboard pasteboardWithUniqueName]`. This means it can be called like this:

```
pboard = NSPasteboard.pasteboardWithUniqueName()
```